# Esri deep learning model is not particularly effective

Tags: lidar, point-cloud, deep-learning

I am using Esri's tree classification deep learning model, in conjunction with the Classify Point Cloud Using Trained Model tool, to classify LiDAR point cloud data in an effort to develop a tree inventory for my city. In the image, green = 'tree' and gray = 'not tree'. Just looking with the naked eye it is clear that an enormous number of tree points are not being identified correctly by the model. I wonder if anyone else has used this model, or has familiarity with deep learning models such that they can shed light on what might account for why this tool/model is doing its job so ineffectively.

[image: Classification results]

Comment: You do not mention how you trained the deep learning model? see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/las-dataset/train-a-point-cloud-model-with-deep-learning.htm

Comment: I did not train it. As I said, it was supplied by ESRI as part of their enterprise license. I haven't really got any idea what went into it. This is all very unfamiliar terrain for me. I am wondering if it is worth it to pursue developing my own trained model. I wonder if, perhaps, the data on which the ESRI model was trained is not sufficiently representative of the data I am using.

Comment: the link It states "Training data is classified points that you provide as examples for the neural network to learn." << you need to teach the model with your data.